# Why is cmis returning an error on datalist item creation in alfresco?

Tags: scala, alfresco, opencmis

I have the following piece of code

```
    try {
          dataList.asInstanceOf[AlfrescoFolder].createItem(
          Map("cmis:objectTypeId" -> "D:dl:contact",
          "cmis:name" -> (data.emailAddress + "_Newsletter_sub"),
          "dl:contactEmail" -> data.emailAddress)
           )
   }
   catch{
          case e: CmisRuntimeException => Logger.error("\n\n ====> silently ignoring this exception because the item is created\n"+e.getMessage+"\n\n");
   }
```

which works fine and creates the data list item.
but it throws an exception with the message 
 **Execution exception[[CmisRuntimeException: Newly created object is not an item! New id: Object Id:**

I'd like to know if this a normal/known issue with this api method and why it's happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of likely reasons which are triggered by constraint violations:

> constraint If the cmis:objectTypeId property value is not an object-type whose base type is cmis:item.
>
> constraint If the cmis:objectTypeId property value is NOT in the list of AllowedChildObjectTypeIds of the parent-folder speciﬁed by folderId.

**References**

- [Oasis Docs: CMIS 1.1 - 2.2.4.6.3 Exceptions Thrown & Conditions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html#x1-2450006)
- [OpenCMIS: Class CMISRuntimeException](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.11.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/exceptions/CmisRuntimeException.html)